# MySQL: Query Assistance Needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to keep it brief here for convenience's sake. I'm new to SQL coding, so please excuse me if I say something weird.
I did not manage to find a solid solution to it (at least one that I would truly understand), which is precisely why I'm posting here as a last resort at this point.

The table code:

```
create table companies (
    company_id mediumint not null auto_increment,
    Name varchar(40) not null,
    Address varchar(40),
    FoundingDate date,
    primary key (company_id)
);

create table employees (
    Employee_id mediumint not null auto_increment,
    Name varchar (40),
    Surname varchar(40),
    primary key (Employee_id)
);

create table accounts (
    Account_id mediumint not null auto_increment,
    Account_number varchar(10) not null,
    CompanyID int(10),
    Date_of_creation date,
    NET_value int(30),
    VAT int(3),
    Total_value int(40),
    EmployeeID int(10) not null,
    Description varchar(40),
    primary key (Account_number)
```

);

Table values are random strings and numbers until I figure this out.

My issue is that I'm stuck at forming correct SQL queries, namely:

- Query all accounts with their designated companies. I need it to show 'NULL' value if an account has no associated company.
- Query that can list all accounts whose date is less than 2018-03-16 or those without a date.
- Query that will print the description of the 'Accounts' table in one column and the number of characters in that description in a different column.
- Query that lists all employees whose names end with '**-gh**' and that have names greater than 5 characters in length.
- Query that will list the top total sum amount.
- Query that will list all accounts that have '**02**' in them (i.e. 3/**02**/05).

If you can answer at least one of these queries and if you can explain how you got to the solution in a simplistic manner, well... I'm afraid I have nothing to offer but honest gratitude! ^^'

Comment: mysql != oracle; the oracle tag blatantly says _"Do NOT use for ... MySQL"_

Comment: Hello Kreaeer please let us know wich DBMS you are using : oracle, sqlserver, postgres, mysql, ...?

Comment: Hi @Kreateer, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, we cannot simply "write" the queries for you. Stack Overflow is intended to be a communal forum -- we would love to see what YOU have tried (even some pseudocode), and we can help adopt that into usable queries.

Comment: Brief? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community, but as Jerry commented, you should really try to show SOMETHING that you have tried just to show what you THINK is needed.  Also, don't just add comments to respond, but edit your original post with additional details / data as people ask questions.

To try and advance you forward though, I will point out two specific links that should help you out.  The first one is a link for the basics on querying explaining the

select [fields] from [what table] join [other tables] where [what is your criteria] -- etc. [Some Basics on querying](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx)

The next give some very good clarification on JOIN conditions of (INNER) JOIN -- which means required record match in BOTH tables being joined, and FULL OUTER JOINS, LEFT JOINs, etc.

After reviewing those, if you STILL have questions, please edit your original question, post some samples of what you THINK is working and let us know (or comment back to a specific answer), and we in the forum can follow-up with you.

HINT, your first query wanting NULL you should get from the visual link via LEFT JOIN.

[A visual representation and samples on querying](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)